# Плавная смена фона сайта при наведении на элемент

Tags: jquery, анимация

Есть 4 ссылки, фоновое изображение висит на `body`.

Нужно при наведении на ссылку плавно менять соответствующий фон.

Использовать просто `:hover` и `transition` не получается, обращение по типу `a:hover body {}` не работает (где-то читал что так можно достучаться или к дочерним или к соседним элементам, точно не помню). Поэтому использую *jquery*.

И вроде бы все плавно работает, но если курсор убрать из красного прямоугольника до окончания анимации `mouseover`, то фон резко меняется на стандартный, а нужно плавно.

Есть еще идея с 4 наложенными один на одного прозрачными фонами, но хотелось бы как-то по другому реализовать.

Пример того что делаю:
https://jsfiddle.net/boarworm/sw6Lwsmf/7/

```
<body>
    <div id="block"></div>
</body>

$('#block').hover(
function(){
$('body').addClass('hover');
}, function(){
$('body').removeClass('hover');
}
);


#block {
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
    background:red;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}

body {
  background: url(ТУТ ССЫЛКА НА ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ. НЕ МОГУ ДОБАВИТЬ БОЛЕЕ 1 ССЫЛКИ);
  transition: background 3s;  
  background-size:cover;   
}

.hover {
    background: url(https://andrewcollector.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/1.jpg);
    transition: background 3s; 
    background-size:cover;    
}
```